# Why "ORA-00940: invalid ALTER command" when i try alter my procedure MY_PRC using this procedure?

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COMPILE_OBJECT(my_type VARCHAR2,
                                           my_name VARCHAR2,
                                           my_package_part VARCHAR2 := NULL) IS
    v_text VARCHAR2(500) := 'ALTER :my_type :my_name COMPILE :my_package_part';
BEGIN
    --try alter objects
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_text USING my_type, my_name, my_package_part;   
END;
```

Comment: If you check `alter` diagrams (for type, package, etc), you will find that it doesn't support bind variables. So you need to concatenate such DDL commands

Answer (score 0):

That would be, as Sayan commented, something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE compile_object (
  2     my_type           VARCHAR2,
  3     my_name           VARCHAR2,
  4     my_package_part   VARCHAR2 := NULL)
  5  IS
  6     v_text  VARCHAR2 (500);
  7  BEGIN
  8     v_text :=
  9           'alter '
 10        || my_type
 11        || ' '
 12        || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (my_name)
 13        || ' compile '
 14        || my_package_part;
 15
 16     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_text;
 17  END;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC compile_object('procedure', 'p_roles', null);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Beware of sql injection!